# WhenEvent versus If function for ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

The following equation works for ParametricNDSolve

```
PKmodel =
  {
   Amt1'[t] == 
    If[0 < Mod[t, \[Tau]] < InfusionTime, Dose/InfusionTime, 0] - 
     CL/V1 Amt1[t] - CLD/V1 Amt1[t] + CLD/V2 Amt2[t] - 
     Vmax Amt1[t]/V1/(Km + Amt1[t]/V1),
   Amt2'[t] == CLD/V1 Amt1[t] - CLD/V2 Amt2[t],
   Amt1[0] == 0,
   Amt2[0] == 0
   };
```

However, the following code did not work for ParametricNDSolve

```
PKmodel =
 {
  Amt1'[t] == -CL/V1 Amt1[t] - CLD/V1 Amt1[t] + CLD/V2 Amt2[t] - 
    Vmax Amt1[t]/V1/(Km + Amt1[t]/V1),
  Amt2'[t] == CLD/V1 Amt1[t] - CLD/V2 Amt2[t],
  Amt1[0] == 0,
  Amt2[0] == 0,
  WhenEvent[0 < Mod[t, \[Tau]] < InfusionTime, 
   Amt1'[t] -> Amt1'[t] + Dose/InfusionTime]
  }
```

Thus, WhenEvent could not work for an input that is over a duration of time?  Any reason for this?

Second, by using If function, the ParametricNDSolve works for solving the ODEs, but I have some numerical issue when execute the following function, although mathematica still gives me the results of AUC across doses.

```
AUClist = 
 NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[Table[(Amt1[Dose][t] /. solns)/(47.9*75), {Dose, 
     doselistug}]], {t, 0, tmax}] (*ug/mL*day*)
```

Any suggestions for solving this?

Comment: An event  (in the case of `WhenEvent`) occurs when the predicate changes from `False` to `True`, according to the docs.  Hence events occur at discrete times and do not happen over a duration.

Comment: So `Fasle` and `True` could not happen over a duration in Mathematica?  That is good to know.  What about numerical issue of `NIntegrate` for the `If` function?

Comment: I tested the following code by specifying values for t and tau and InfusionTime and the mathematica return to me `True` or `False`: `0 < Mod[t, \[Tau]] < InfusionTime`.  With the change of t, `0 < Mod[t, \[Tau]] < InfusionTime` will take different values of `True` or `False`.  Why it is not allowed in `WhenEvent` and `ParametricNDSolve`?

Comment: As @MichaelE2 said, `WhenEvent` only watches for when the first argument changes from `False` to `True` -- not the reverse.  What I was thinking of when I mentioned `WhenEvent` earlier was treating the infusion as a discrete pulse: `WhenEvent[t==Mod[t, \[Tau]], Amt1[t] -> Amt1[t] + Dose]`.

Comment: In general, try to include *all* the required info in your questions.  For example, how did you call `ParametricNDSolve` and what numerical issues does that `NIntegrate` cause?

Comment: The "when" in "when the predict changes..." is a discrete time/instant.  The predicate cannot be changing from `False` to `True` throughout a duration. The notion of "event" here is that time at which the change occurs.  `WhenEvent` does not mean "when the condition is true, do *this*."  (The way to accomplish the equivalent of your `If[]` is to use `DiscreteVariables`; indeed, `NDSolve` rewrites the `If[]` in terms of `WhenEvent` and discrete variables, unless you prevent it.)

Comment: How could write this out by a combination of `WhenEvent` and `ParametricNDSolve` with `DiscreteVariable` to do the same thing as the combination of `If` with `ParametericNDSolve`?